# How can I resurrect my mercenary?

Tags: diablo-ii

I've read in various guides and FAQs that Diablo II mercenaries can be resurrected from the NPC who lets you hire them; however, I can't find the option to do so.  I'm in Act II and Greiz only offers the options to talk or to hire a new mercenary.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They can be resurrected by talking to one of the NPC folks in town... for a price.

The higher the level of your mercenary, the more expensive it will be. The maximum cost to resurrect your mercenary is 50,000 gold.

Resurrections can be performed by the following NPCs in their respective acts:

- Act I: Kashya
- Act II: Greiz
- Act III: Asheara
- Act IV: Tyreal
- Act V: Qual-Kehk

If you don't see an option to resurrect your mercenary, then you either:

- Do not currently have a mercenary active (haven't hired one)
- Your mercenary is active and alive

You can check to see if you have one active if you press <kbd>O</kbd> to bring up it's stat/inventory menu.

Comment: My hired mercenary just died, I haven't even relaunched the game, but the option doesn't show up.  Pressing "o" when I have a mercenary hired does nothing.

Comment: @Gnomees Which mercenary did you have? Have you tried going back to the NPC you hired them from? Do you see the Merc's portrait icon on the top left corner? Press "Z" to toggle the portrait iron for your followers and summons.

Comment: Have you patched the game, or playing as the standard install?  I think most of the merc enhancements were added in a later patch.

Comment: @Krazer — (I'm her roommate.)  She was using one of the mercs from Greiz in Act II, the portrait appeared in the corner, and she's patched up to the latest available from Blizzard (1.12?).

Comment: @BenBlank Is this on the Battle.net realms or on (offline) single player? The latest patch is 1.13c for Diablo 2.

Comment: @Krazer I tried logging into Battle.net and it said it couldn't identify my version.  So, I reinstalled, then connected to Battle.net as Administrator; it patched up and everything's working fine now.  Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

Your diablo game is probly not the expansion the option to do most of the stuff with the merch was added in the expasion pack sorry man u need lord of destruction not just the reg diablo 2